# Wildcard Url Pattern using htaccess

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, random

i am looking for htaccss code. i want like if some one vist

```
domain.com/folder/ver-234123.html
domain.com/folder/ver-4234234.html
domain.com/folder/ver-kahsdkf.html
```

so it all baiscally open `domain.com/folder/index.php`

i will randomize the number/digits after ver- via php.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use mod_rewrite.

Assuming "/folder" actually exists and this .htaccess would be within it.

This should be a fairly simple rewrite. Something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?ver-[a-z0-9]*\.html index.php [L,QSA]
```